# Swift: do I need to create a new immutable array for function return?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, immutability

Say a function/method has a local mutable array and the return type of the function/method is an immutable array. It's a common practice to create a new immutable array to be returned:

```
- (NSArray *)someArray {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]
    // ...do something with array
    return array.copy
}
```

However, in Swift, since the array is a value type, do I still need to do the same?

```
func someArray() -> [MyValue] {
    var array = [MyValue]()
    // do something with array
    return array // or return Array(array)?
}
```

Comment: Just return the array. In Swift, Arrays are value types and being copied (although, in your case, it is not copied, but this is a tricky implementation detail you don't have to care about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example:

```
func someArray() -> [MyValue] {
    var array = [MyValue]()

    //...do something with array
    return array
}
```

It will depend on how you use the function.

If you do:

1. `let arrTest = someArray()`

   - `let` will make `arrTest` immutable
2. `var arrTest = someArray()`

   - `var` will make `arrTest` mutable

`Array`s in swift are `Struct`s, and `Struct`s are value types so your function `someArray()` is basically returning a copy of the array.
The creation of the array inside the function doesn't determine it's mutability.

---

#### So to answer your question:

**No!** You don't need to do the same.
Just create the array normally in swift.

Comment: "The creation of the array inside the function doesn't determine it's mutability." <- this enlightened me, thanks!